# En MySQL, como sumar valores maximos de un rango de fecha?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, sum

Dada la siguiente tabla:

| data_date | data_totalenergy |
| --- | --- |
| 2021/08/10 | 22 |
| 2021/08/10 | 35 |
| 2021/08/11 | 20 |
| 2021/08/11 | 31 |
| 2021/08/12 | 14 |
| 2021/08/12 | 10 |
| 2021/08/13 | 4 |
| 2021/08/13 | 10 |

Necesito realizar una consulta el cual me de la suma total de los valores máximos en un rango de fecha definido. Por ejemplo, selecciono los valores máximos de la fecha 2021/08/10  hasta 2021/08/12 que serian 35,31 y 14 y la suma de ellos que seria 80.

La siguiente consulta con la que estoy trabajando me da los valores máximos deseados y los agrupa por día, ahora, necesito poder sumar esos valores de esos días para poder obtener el resultado final.

```
SELECT MAX(data_totalenergy)
  FROM admin_proyectdb.`data` 
  WHERE data_date >= '2021-08-01 20:20:00'
  AND data_date < '2021-08-19 20:59:00'
  GROUP BY DAY(data_date)
```

Comment: Intenta con `SELECT MAX(data_totalenergy), SUM(values) AS total FROM ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Únicamente te falta sumar todos esos máximos que has ido localizando y, para eso, están las subconsultas:

```
SELECT SUM(data) FROM (
        SELECT MAX(data_totalenergy) data
          FROM admin_proyectdb.`data` 
          WHERE data_date >= '2021-08-01 20:20:00'
          AND data_date < '2021-08-19 20:59:00'
          GROUP BY DAY(data_date)
    ) c1;
```

Cuidado con la función `DAY()`, tal vez quieras utilizar `DATE()` y no son lo mismo.

Comment: Muchas gracias! me sirvió para solucionar mi problema! 

Answer (score 3):

Puedes construir una tabla para de ella hacer el sum, tal como:

```sql
select
  sum(t.max)
from
(
  select
    data.date_f,
    max(data.values) as max
  from
    data
     where
     data.date_f >= '2021-08-10 00:00:00' and data.date_f <= '2021-08-13 23:59:59'
   group by data.date_f
)t
```

He construido el ejemplo en http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9712c9/46/0

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda! Me dio una idea! 